# Remove side spacing from button in linearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this layout designed so far

[image]

Notice the side space around both the buttons with the name "save" that I have marked with red color, I want to remove that extra spacing.

Both the buttons are wrapped inside linearlayout with orientation set to "vertical", I tried using `layout_weight, marginLeft and marginRight` but no success.

Here's how the xml code looks like only for the buttons inside the linearlayout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <!--This layout is for save and change currency buttons-->


        <Button
             android:id="@+id/saveButton"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Save"
             android:layout_weight="1"
          />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/currencyButton"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Save"
             android:layout_weight="1"
         />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Just for extra information the above linearlayout is wrapped inside one more linearlayout which controls the layout of full activity

**EDIT**

Full code for the main activity xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/layer_list"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftCurrencySection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="GBP"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0.00"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightCurrencySection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="USD"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="0.00"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@null"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--End of This layout is for typing currency values-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <!--This layout is for save and change currency buttons-->


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/currencyButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--End of  save and change currency buttons-->

    <!--Begin Layout for calculator begin-->

    <GridLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >


        <Button android:text="1"

            />

        <Button android:text="2" />

        <Button android:text="3" />



        <Button android:text="4" />

        <Button android:text="5" />

        <Button android:text="6" />



        <Button android:text="7" />

        <Button android:text="8" />

        <Button android:text="9" />


        <Button android:text="." />

        <Button android:text="0" />

        <Button android:text="Del" />


    </GridLayout>
    <!--End Layout for calculator-->
    <!--End Layout for calculator End-->


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire xml file you're using and also if this is a fragment then your main activity xml file?

Comment: Remove the padding from the parent layout container

Comment: in your both Button property android:layout_width="match_parent";

Comment: @eclipse1203: I have updated the full code. To-cricket_007: I tried removing the padding from the main parent layout container, but there is still minor space left out

Comment: The default styling for buttons includes some padding on each edge so that the buttons don't bump up against each other or other widgets when placed adjacent to each other. This is true for every version of Android I have worked with.  If you want buttons (and many other widgets) to be able to render flush against others, you have to provide your own background styles (usually a 9-patch) for the widgets.

Comment: @ArpitPatel: I tried match_parent as well, no luck

Comment: You are not using weightsum. and layout_weight well.

Comment: in which container you are using  android:layout_weight. you must use 
android:layout_width="0dp" instead android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: IS this fragment's layout ?

Comment: @DougStevenson: Your comment makes some sense to me, I tried removing padding from my parent linearlayout, The result was that my buttons expanded. But it still has minor spacing which might me due to default styling as you mentioned. Could you provide background style for the same. Because the concept you talking about seems to be alien for me

Comment: Can you show me your activity _main and layer_list?? This might be a problem for that just remove and check.

Comment: @DougStevenson is correct. Android has default padding for button backgrounds. To prove this set this attribute on your buttons and you'll see they extend to the edges  android:background="#00ff00"

Comment: @IshqMehta the padding is built into the 9-patch for the background image of the button that defines its shape and color.  It's not a padding value that you can specify in the view itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson: Could you post an answer for this? I tried layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight to -16dp. It removed the extra left space. But I wonder whether it's the right way to do it!

Comment: @IshqMehta The correct answer is to set your own background to the button like this android:background="#00ff00"

Answer (score 0):

There are many people to thanks over here, who pointed out my mistake and also guided me to correct way of removing that extra space from either sides of the button.

First ***I had to remove the padding from my parent linearlayout. I removed paddingLeft and PaddingRight. Which removed the major part of the space.*** Thanks to **cricket_007** for pointing this out.

Even after removing the space there was still a bit of space left out like 1 or 2dp. This was apparently due to some default styling in android as pointed out by **Doug Stevenson**.

To remove this last form of space, I had to apply some sort of background mentioned by eclipse for example `android:background="#00ff00"`

Applying the above attribute removed that extra space, this is due to 9patch in android. [Learn more about it over here.](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)